# Konev Linear Algebra problems

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> **Problem 12**: Let $A(2,1,-1)$ and $B(8,-2,11)$ be the endpoints of a linear segment $\overline{AB}$.
>
> Find the coordinates of the point $C$ on $\overline{AB}$ such that $\overline{AC}:\overline{CB}$ is $2:1$.

I need help to solve this problem.

Comment: If you haven't already, you should draw a picture. A 2D example will suffice. Draw a point A, another point B. You want to find the point C that divides AB into a 2:1 ratio. Let $v$ be the vector that, when you add $v$ to $A$ you get to $B.$ In other words, $B = A + v.$ Do you understand why $C = A + (2/3) v$ ?

Comment: Not yet, but I decided. I think that the answer will be v=<6, -1, 7>. Is it correct ?

Comment: Your answer is correct, but you should make sure you understand how to think about these problems systematically.

Comment: I don't understand 100%. Could you send a photo ?

Comment: Please consult your own textbook again and try drawing some examples for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A(x_A, y_A, z_A)$ and $B(x_B, y_B, z_B)$ be the endpoints of a linear segment $AB$.

Let $C(x_C, y_C, z_C)$ be a point such that $AC:CB = \lambda$.

Then,

$$
 x_C = \frac{x_A + \lambda x_B}{1+λ},\quad y_C = \frac{y_A + \lambda y_B}{1+λ}, \quad z_C = \frac{z_A + \lambda z_B}{1+λ}. 
$$

In your example,

- $x_A = 2, y_A = 1, z_A = -1$.
- $x_B = 8, y_B = -2, z_B = 11$.
- $λ = 2$.

$$
 x_C = \frac{2 + 2\cdot 8}{1+2} = 6,\quad y_C = \frac{1 + 2\cdot (-2)}{1+2} = -1, \quad z_C = \frac{-1 + 2\cdot 11}{1+2} = 7. 
$$